# How to access nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, nested-forms

I would like to get some nested params. I have an Order that has many Items and these Items each have a Type. i would like to get the type_id parameter from the controllers create method.

```
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
@order.items.each do |f|
  f.item_type_id = Item_type.find_by_name(f.item_type_id).id
end
```

The reason is that i want the user to be able to create new item_types in the view. When they do that i use an AJAX call add them to the db. When they post the form i get names of the item_type in the item_type_id parameter and i want to find the correct item_type and set the id to that

Comment: You should be more specific. Where do you want to get this parameter? In controller in update/create method? Or in view in new/edit action? Add some code - it always make it easier to guess what you want :)

Comment: There, updated the question a bit :) was in a hurry when i posted it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To access the nested fields from `params` do the following:

```
params[:order][:items_attributes].values.each do |item|
  item[:type_id]
end if params[:order] and params[:order][:items_attributes]
```

Above solution will work ONLY if you have declared the correct associations and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Comment: Seems like that is what i need. However, i get a undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass - error

Comment: It looks like `params` does not have `items_attributes`. Print `params` to check the value.

Comment: Parameters: {
"authenticity_token"=>"61m5JPrQ3ZS3fxAxoh1cgmmhO5U+WCcYZ2RykLIHc3o=", "order"=>{
  "items_attributes"=>
  {"1270891910372"=>
    {"price"=>"", "text"=>"", "amount"=>"", "kind_id"=>"Bla", "_destroy"=>""}
  }, "total_price"=>"2"}
}

Comment: You have to extract the :order first. Also I don't see `type_id` in the `items_attributes`. I have updated my answer take a look.