# Rails: How to access child model params in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two **models** `submission` and `upload` where:

```
#Submission.rb
attr_accessible :id, :photo_id, :uploads_attributes
has_many :uploads, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true

#Upload.rb:
attr_accessible :id,:photo_type_id    
belongs_to :submission
```

In my `submissions_controller.rb` I can access `photo_id` with:

`params[:submission][:photo_id]`,

however I don't know how to access its child model's `photo_type_id`

I tried

`params[:uploads_attributes][0][:package_type_id]`

but it doesnt work, ig gives me:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

In my view **page source** I have:

```
name="submission[photo_id]"

**in fields_for:**

name="submission[uploads_attributes][0][photo_type_id]"
```

Any idea what should be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the answer here:

[How to access nested params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610263/how-to-access-nested-params)

in my case, I used:

```
params[:submission][:uploads_attributes]["0"][:photo_type_id]
```

Just need to change the `[0]` to `["0"]`